# Should it be 'is' or 'are' after a number with a unit?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, numbers

What would be the right form of ***to be*** in the examples below?

> Five miles [is/are] a long way to walk.

> Preliminary results [is/are] better than no results at all.

Comment: Measures of distance (five miles) and time (ten minutes) are somewhat forgiving when it comes to agreement in number, but _results_ is plural and must take the plural form of the verb (_are._)

Answer (score -1):

Use standard plural construction with "results are".  Use standard singular construction with "is a long ... walk". "A preliminary result is" also standard usage.  "The five miles are fraught with danger" uses plural, because the sentence does not cast the total distance into a single unit.